# How can I Show the first, second, and third deposit in every Member name? Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot

[image]

[image]

How can I Show the first, second, and third deposit in every Member name? Pivot Table.

Comment: Show us your data and maybe it will be easier for us to understand.

Comment: With your data and in relation to "efg456", are you saying that first deposit is on the 1-Jan, the second is on the 3-Jan and the 3rd deposit is also the 3-Jan?

Comment: @Skin yes.
example: abc 123 first deposit: jan 1 sec: jan 2 third: jan 3 and his 4th and so on will be diregard. I just need their 1st, 2nd and 3rd deposit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your spreadsheet starts at cell **A1** and your data is **sorted by date**, create a new column to the right called **Deposit No.** and put this formula into cell `D2` ...

`=COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)`

... then fill down.

[image: Data]

Now include that field in your pivot table and filter on it.

[image: Pivot]